# Share Android device using Remote Desktop

Tags: networking, windows-10, remote-desktop, android, android-studio

I usually work in my office using Android Studio and an Android tablet linked to my workstation through an USB cable, so I can run my application in a direct way.

Sometimes I need to work from my own house and I have a Remote Desktop between my personal PC and my workstation, both running Windows 10; in this case, for running an application, I have to build it remotely, pass the APK file locally, move the APK inside my tablet (that I have with me at my place) and install it from inside the Android environment, that's  quite a slow process.

There's a way to share my Android device linked at my place's PC through the Remote Desktop so I can "see" it from my workstation?

PS: I tried to select it from the Remote Desktop panel before connection, in Local Resources, but I still can't see it when the connection is established.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Vysor, it is a grat app, if you pay the subscription 10USD per year you can connect the device wireless to the computer